# Rest API Responsive Web App

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, site, web

I am creating a responsive intranet Web Application using AngularJS and Bootstrap (not a SharePoint App) that will be ported into PhoneGap which leverages SharePoint Server 2013 as its back end (CRUD operations on lists). Since it's going on phones we are using the Rest API only for all calls on the client side.

The web site is hosted on same IIS with the SharePoint Server but its on a different port (it is not a SharePoint Application). I have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin for the port of the web application to help avoid cross domain issue.

The users are all from Active Directory. The SharePoint Server is NTLM Auth, in order to do any requests, I have to use the NTLM.js library (https://github.com/erlandranvinge/ntlm.js/tree/master) to create the challenge for me so that I could successfully send each of my $http calls and there are lots of calls.

I feel like this is horribly inefficient plus that library does not work on IE or FireFox consistently.

The big challenge is that I am supposed to create a web site that works on the desktop browser and then as a PhoneGap app, and I don't know the best approach for authorizing users to rest apis from this site. Please recommend a better approach if you understand the challenge that I am facing developing this intranet web site.

Would it work better if the SharePoint Server supported Forms Based Authentication? Would I then be able to login users to a sharepoint url to get a cookie and then use that to access the Rest APIs?

Any guidance would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: You can use REST towards 2013 (at least 365) from anywhere without apps (must register a dummy-app for OAuth, must obtain access token server-side), I can tell you more about this if it is what you want. But is there any reason you can't use apps? This sounds like the perfect setup for a provider-hosted app

Comment: You're right, I suppose I could deploy the application as a provider hosted app. But how can I go about getting an oauth token for the rest api calls to avoid ntlm authentication.

Comment: You can get the token through TokenHelper (oauthauthorize.aspx), at least for 365. But do you really need that, why can't you use CSOM? REST to your server and Web API + CSOM.

Comment: I set up a Web Api with CSOM and it seems to give me more control. Although, whenever I create a list item, it says the item was created by my System Account which is the SharePoint Application Pool identity. I do recall on one of my first tests it actually persisted my user id instead but I can't remember what I changed that may have caused it to use the System Account now.